# More than 4 dimensional arrays using F# - cannot initialize object

Tags: .net, arrays, f#, hdf5

I play with HDF5DotNet (see http://hdf5.net/). There is a class `H5Array` which has a lot of constructors of this kind:

```
new 'Type []
new 'Type [,]
new 'Type [,,]
new 'Type [,,]
new 'Type [,,,]
new 'Type [,,,,]
new 'Type [,,,,,]
...
```

I write

```
let data = Array2D.create 256 512 4.
let test = H5Array data
```

Even for a 2D array I get an error saying:

> internal error: F# supports a maxiumum .NET array dimension of 4

My two questions are:

1. How to make it work for the 2D data?
2. How to make it work for more than 4 dimensional data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, for question #2, I expect you'd use Array.Create

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k.aspx

to make arrays with large rank.  But I wonder if #1 is a compiler bug?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This `let data = Array.CreateInstance (float.GetType(), [|1; 2; 3; 4; 5|] )` gives the same error. Should I report this behaviour somewhere or will you do that? BTW: Is there any work around to make it work? The only I can think of now is to create another C# project and wrap the constructors.

Comment: It it a limitation of the F# compiler/language (the language spec says F# only supports up to rank 4).  This is the first time we recall encountering such a real case of higher rank 'in the wild'.  Wrapping the constructors in a C# type that exposes some static methods that call those constructors and prevents F# from needing to see the high-rank arrays may indeed work around it, let me know if not.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But at least it should always work for ranks bellow 4 when the object has constructors with higher ranks as well.

Comment: (Another workaround may be to invoke the constructor via reflection.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. To close this topic. Should I report it somewhere? To me it is for the low ranks a bug :)

Comment: I've reported it, but I doubt that we'll change anything, especially if a workaround is sufficient.